# When a document is deleted or published in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, typescript, pnpjs

I have a requirement to develop a solution based on SPFx, namely, when a document is deleted from a document library or a document is published (got main version) in a document library in SharePoint online, do something? How can I get "notification" or "getChanges" or other opportunity to handle and solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in SPFX. You'll have to use a web hook or a remote event receiver.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-remote-event-receivers-in-sharepoint

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks

Answer (score 0):

You could not achieve this with SPFx, I would suggest you create a remote event receiver in SharePoint Add-ins to acheve this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins